# Xcode Crashlytics Issue in Cocoa pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods, crashlytics

In My project i use cocoa pod.

My pod For Crashlytics is :

---

```
pod 'Crashlytics'
```

---

But After install pod i getting 36 error of linker.

here i attach screenshot of error.

[Error of pod 'Crashlytics'](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IPEFh.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: show all of your pod file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Crashlytics is now part of fabric, you should add two line to your target:

```
target 'YourTarget' do
pod 'Fabric'
pod 'Crashlytics'
end
```

By the way all install process is integrated with fabric app, you should look better on their [site](https://www.crashlytics.com/blog/introducing-fabric/)